# ¿Cómo puedo extraer resultados en YOLO V8?

Tags: python, python-3.7, inteligencia-artificial

Buen día. Alguien que sepa, ¿Cómo es que puedo poner en una nueva ventana el resultado de la detección, de mi modelo? Me refiero a que en yolo se pinta un cuadro cuando se detecta algún objeto de las respectivas clases entrenadas. Pero lo que yo busco, es extraer la imagen de ese cuadro. Me encantaría que me apoyaran. Adjunto mi código de como estoy relacionado con la detección y mostrando la imagen del resultado.

```
`# Importar las librerías
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

# Leer nuestro modelo
model = YOLO("cars.pt")

# Ruta de la imagen
image_path = "car_image.jpg"

# Leer la imagen
frame = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Leemos resultados
resultados = model.predict(frame, imgsz=640, conf=0.40)

# Mostramos resultados
anotaciones = resultados[0].plot()

# Mostramos nuestra imagen
cv2.imshow("DETECCION Y SEGMENTACION", anotaciones)

# Esperar por cualquier tecla y luego cerrar la ventana
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

Podrías guarda el fotograma con la mascara ya puesta, opencv permite hace eso, otra opción es salvar el fotograma y la predicción de yolo como txt para usarlo en un futuro entrenamiento, por ultimo podría hacer que opencv haga una captura de la ventana que tienes para la detección, no es una solución elegante pero es rápida y fácil de implementar.